# .Net Core 3.1 fails to bind properties while using ajax call before submitting the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using .net core 3.1 razor pages. I have a page with a property. I'm using a jQuery ajax call in my page. Sometimes though my field was filled, but the property got null in my PostAsync method. After spending much time, I found that `MyProperty` was null (not bound) when I called my $.ajax function in the page before submitting it! Is it a bug in .net core or have I forgotten some settings?

MyPage.chtml:

```
...
<form method="post">
    My Property: <input asp-for="MyProperty" /><br />
    <button id="doAction" type="button">Do some action in server</button><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#doAction').click(function(){
            $.ajax(
                '/api/myaction/doSomeAction/2',
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function() { alert('Some action done successfully.'); }
                }
        });
   });
</script>
...
```

MyPage.chtml.cs:

```
[BoundProperty]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
...
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var temp = MyProperty;
    ...
}
```

MyAction controller class:

```
[Route( "api/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class MyActionController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost( "doSomeAction/{code?}" )]
   public async Task<dynamic> PostAsync( int code )
   {
        // do some actions...
   }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app , IWebHostEnvironment env )
{
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints( endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute( "default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}" );
        } );
    ...
}
```

Scenarios:

1. Fill MyProperty with `"MyValue"` and submit form => `MyProperty == "MyValue"` (OK).
2. Fill MyProperty with `"MyValue"`; click **`doAction`** button; then submit form => `MyProperty == null` (binding property failed!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly where your problem is, but this kind of error will not occur under normal circumstances. You can see my working example below.

Index.chtml:

```
@page
@model xxxxx.IndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<form method="post">
    My Property: <input asp-for="MyProperty" /><br />
    <button id="doAction" type="button">Do some action in server</button><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#doAction').click(function () {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '/api/myaction/doSomeAction/2',
                        type: 'POST',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                        },
                        success: function () { alert('Some action done successfully.'); }
                    })
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

In your startup,add:

```
//...
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Index.chtml.cs:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        //...
        return Page();
    }
```

MyAction controller class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyActionController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("doSomeAction/{code?}")]
    public async Task<dynamic> PostAsync(int code)
    {
        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu, thanks for spending your time my real case is complex and i simplified it here. May be there are some other reasons leading to issue i described. Can you say why did you use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your index.chtml? It's generatod automatically according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration).

Comment: Because yours is razor pages, if you want to use Ajax to pass the request, you need to add it manually.

Comment: You can try my code and see it whether work.

Comment: There was an error in my `$.ajax` function's options (in my real case ofcourse, not here!) and now everything is ok fixing it. B.W. @Yinqiut I'm not using `@Html.antiForgeryToken()` and no problem is found. Try your project removing that piece of code. It would work fine.

Comment: Yes, antiForgeryToken will be included in the mvc project. I forgot this. Your mvc project is not a Razor-page project.:)

Comment: In short, I am glad you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you suppose to be sending data into your ajax post call,

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
       <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#doAction').click(function(){
            $.ajax(
                '/api/myaction/doSomeAction/2',
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:$(form).serializeArray();
                    success: function() { alert('Some action done successfully.'); }
                }
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: No, I just call an api to send a sms to user.

Comment: then you can use $.post https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: I know $.post and that is not my problem. The problem is after an ajax call, it seems that values get reset somewhere in the form. If you fill the value again and submit the form, value can be captured in the server, else, it will be null!